# How to fix React.useEffect and useCallback circular loop when updating a state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm fetching some data from an API, but since I am using this data to update a state within a `useEffect`, this state becomes a required dependency, which causes a circular loop.

`state is updated -> useEffect is called -> state is updated ...`

I read a lot of answers and articles about that, but I couldn't find an answer to my specific question.

This is my initial code:

```
let [state, setState] = React.useState<IDataSource[]>([])

React.useEffect(() => {
    let dataSource: IDataSource[] = []
   
    dataFetched.forEach((item, index) => {
        // Some logic
    })
    
    setState(state.concat(dataSource))

}, [dataFetched, state])
```

Then I decided to update the state using a function called by `useEffect` and passing an argument:

```
let [state, setState] = React.useState<IDataSource[]>([])

const updateData = (arg: IDataSource[] => {
    setData(state.concat(arg))
}

React.useEffect(() => {
    let dataSource: IDataSource[] = []
   
    dataFetched.forEach((item, index) => {
        //Some logic
    })
    
    updateData(dataSource)
}, [dataFetched, updateData])
```

This works, but since I have `updateData` as a `useEffect depency` I have to wrap the function with `useCallback`:

```
const updateData = React.useCallback((arg: IDataSource[]) => {
    setData(state.concat(arg))
}, [state])

React.useEffect(() => {
    let dataSource: IDataSource[] = []
   
    dataFetched.forEach((item, index) => {
        //Some logic
    })
    
    updateData(dataSource)
}, [dataFetched, updateData])
```

But in this case I also have `state` as a `useCallback depency` and I'm back to the starting problem, a circular loop.

Apparently I should use `React.useRef` when I have an array as `useEffect dependency`, but `state` is not just an array, it is actually a state, which is being set with `useState`, so I don't know how to do that in this case or even if this is possible.

Is there a way to solve that?

Comment: what is `setPatients` ?

Comment: @Olivier Boissé Sorry, it was just a lack of attention, it should be `setData`. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove `data` from the `useEffect` array and call `setState` with an updater function like this `setState(prevState => prevState.concat(dataSource))`

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState<IDataSource[]>([])

React.useEffect(() => {
    const dataSource: IDataSource[] = []
   
    dataFetched.forEach((item, index) => {
        // Some logic to fill the dataSource array ??
    })
    
    setState(prevState => prevState.concat(dataSource))
}, [dataFetched])
```